# Make taxonomy lists collapsible in a views BEF

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

Similar to the module [Term Reference Tree](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree) is there a way to make long taxonomy list filters collapsible? My use case would be for pages similar to kobejet.com/speakraku - where the list is so long it makes the filter unwieldy for users.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the [Chosen module](https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen).  Doesn't make things collapsible but it does make finding options in long lists easier.  Will work across all forms automatically so even helps with admin forms.

One of my standard modules to install on all sites.

Answer (score 0):

Woot! The simple hierarchical select module - https://www.drupal.org/project/shs currently works fantastically with views in d8. You can see my working example here - www.kobejet.com/lessons